# Scatter SQL Equivalent

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In Visual FoxPro there is a command called Scatter. I can go to a certain record and use the command "Scatter Memvar Memo" and it copies the record and all fields or chosen fields to memory. Then I can insert the record into another table.

My question:

Is there a similar command in SQL 2008R2 where I can do the same thing? Or how would I go about doing that?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select into cursor and then insert from the cursor.

Comment: Nice! To simple. Thanks :)